# Java spring JPA Repository Entity is not deleted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my code, I fetch an entity and try to delete it, using the interface `ProductRepository` which extends `JpaRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {}
```

Code, and `System.out.println()` output from code:

```
@PostMapping("/admin/product/delete")
public String deleteProduct(
        @RequestParam String productId
){
    Long id = Long.parseLong(productId);
    System.out.println("long id from deleteProduct: " + id);

    productService.deleteProductById(id);
    return "redirect:/product";
}
```

sysout:

```
 long id from deleteProduct: 38
```

Service method `deleteProductById()`:

```
public void deleteProductById(long productId){
    Product product = productRepository.getOne(productId);
    System.out.println("Product:\n" + product);
    productRepository.delete(product);}
```

sysout from `deleteProductById`:

```
Product:  Product{id=38, productName='zip',
producer=lightmarket.mvc.model.domain.Producer@182a383}
```

But the entity is not deleted... 
I must point out that all other CRUD operations work. Create, Update, Read - all are alright! Only 'delete' is not working.

Comment: Increase the log verbosity of some hibernate package to understand what happens : `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` may help

Comment: Where are this strings must be increased? in application.properties?

Comment: in the log appender. Yes add them in application.properties.

Comment: Have you tried to put an @Transactional annotation at the service method?

Comment: Be wary of linked entities - in my case, a linked entity of the deleted one was getting updated within the same transaction, as a result of which Hibernate was automatically unscheduling the original entity deletion (found out thru Hibernate DEBUG logs - thanks @davidxxx!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JpaRepository` extends `CrudRepository`, so you can use:

[`Crudrepository.deleteById()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#deleteById-ID-) which in the case of your generic types, takes a long (See the documentation at ).

[image]

So, in your service, you would have something like:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repo;

    public void deleteProductById(Long id) {

        System.out.println("Deleting product with id: " + id);

        // USE deleteById(Long id) and directly pass the id
        // Defined in CrudRepository
        repo.deleteById(id);

        // DON'T use delete() and pass a product
        //repo.delete(product);

    }
}
```

Then your controller calls `service.deleteProductById()` from the service like normal

See documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#deleteById-ID-

Comment: that's exactly what my service is called: repo.deleteById(id);

Comment: Yes, but within your method `deleteProductById()` you are calling `JpaRepository.delete(Product product)` passing a `Product` object rather than calling `JpaRepository.deleteById(Long id)` and passing the long. My point is that you should not create a `Product` object and call `delete()` and expect your repository to find that matching product because we do not know if it is using `equals()` method, or some other method. You should directly use the `deleteById()` method that is defined in `CrudRepository`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is something wrong with your equals and hashcode of the Product class and the object you load from database is not the same you are trying to delete.

A better way for deleting a product by id would be using the id instead of the product object.

You could replace

```
productRepository.delete(product);
```

with

```
productRepository.delete(productId);
```

where productId is of type Long.
This would also avoid the additional query.

Comment: `CrudRepository<T, ID>` is a `CrudRepository<Product, Long>`. The `delete(T entity)` method accepts an argument of type `T` ,in this case `Product`, and it would probably use the `product.equals()` method to check for the correct product to delete. If this method is not overridden, by default the address of the object reference in memory is used to for comparison, which is unique. So, we use `deleteById(ID id)` which in this case accepts a `Long`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#deleteById-ID-